# How to send the grid data inside beforeSaveRow to perform ajax validation

Tags: jqgrid, before-save

I have a problem in the approach for validation in server side and display the error if exist. I use before Save Row function to achieve this.

```
  $.extend(true, $.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
    beforeSaveRow: function (options, rowid) {
        //alert("called");
        jQuery('#' + rowid + '_statusFlag').css('background','red');
        jQuery('#' + rowid + '_statusFlag').attr('title','error messages goes here...');
        return false; // return false break submiting
    }
});
```

Here inside the function, I wish to perform an ajax call with the row data. How will I serialize or get the postdata so that I can send the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see an example to how you can get your postdata:

```
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
            beforeSaveRow: function (options, rowid) {

                $(this).find('input').each(function () {

                    var name = this.name;
                    var value = $(this).val();

                });
                alert("called");
                //jQuery('#' + rowid + '_statusFlag').css('background', 'red');
                //jQuery('#' + rowid + '_statusFlag').attr('title', 'error messages goes here...');
                return false; // return false break submiting
            }
        });
```